# Adding values of two char arrays

Tags: c, arrays

How can i add two numerical values from two `char` arrays?

Example :  `char array1[2]="12", array2[2]="98";`

I want to add the values of `array1` and `array2`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning :

```
char array1[2]="12", array2[2]="98";
```

the size 2 is not enough to save the null terminating character, must be 3

A more secure way is to let the compiler decide by itself the dimension :

```
char array1[]="12", array2[]="98";
```

> I want to add two numerical values from two string arrays.

There are several ways to do, the less secure is to use `atoi` because even the numbers are invalid you have a result, the more secure way is to use `strtol` if they contain a `long` (you did not say if they can contain a double etc).

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
  char array1[]="12", array2[]="98";
  long l1, l2;
  char * endp;

  errno = 0;

  l1 = strtol(array1, &endp, 10);
  if ((errno != 0) || (*array1 == 0) || (*endp != 0)) {
    printf("not (only) a valid long in %s\n", array1);
    return -1;
  }

  l2 = strtol(array2, &endp, 10);
  if ((errno != 0) || (*array2 == 0) || (*endp != 0)) {
    printf("not (only) a valid long in %s\n", array2);
    return -1;
  }

  printf("%ld + %ld = %ld\n", l1, l2, l1+l2);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
12 + 98 = 110
```

Note the programs does not indicate an error with `" 12"` but indicates one with `"12 "`, if you want to also refuse `" 12"` you can do :

```
if ((errno != 0) || !isdigit(*array1) || (*endp != 0))
```

and same for *array1*. *isdigit* is declared in `#include <ctype.h>`

---

From your remark

> a easy way to do that will be good for me

If you are *absolutely sure* the arrays contain the valid external representation of a *int* you can use *atoi* (*atol* for a *long* etc). *atoi* also bypass the spaces before the expected *int*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char array1[]="12", array2[]="98";

  printf("%s + %s = %d\n", array1, array2, atoi(array1) + atoi(array2));
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
12 + 98 = 110
```

But again warning, `atoi("aze")` silently returns 0 like if you do `atoi("0")`

---

An alternative of the *strtod* family is *sscanf*, it is more secure than the *atoi* family because it indicates if you read or not a portion of a number and if there is or not an overflow. If you just use `"%d"` for instance you cannot know if there is something after the read integer, but you can use `"%d%c"` still checking *sscanf* returns 1 (if there is something after the number *sscanf* returns 2) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
  char array1[]="12", array2[]="98";
  int l1, l2;
  char c;

  errno = 0;
  if ((sscanf(array1, "%d%c", &l1, &c) != 1) || errno){
    printf("not (only) a valid int in '%s'\n", array1);
    return -1;
  }

  if ((sscanf(array2, "%d%c", &l2, &c) != 1) || errno) {
    printf("not (only) a valid int in '%s'\n", array2);
    return -1;
  }

  printf("%d + %d = %d\n", l1, l2, l1+l2);
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra a1.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
12 + 98 = 110
```

Like the other functions the spaces before the expected number are also bypassed.

Comment: Your answer is correct but i am a noob that's why i wasn't able to understand your answer. So a easy way to do that will be good for me.

Comment: @Saurabh I edited my answer with a simpler way, but warning that supposes you know *for sure* the arrays contain the valid representation of an _int_ etc. If you don't understand I strongly encourage you to look at the documentation of _strtol_. Even being simple a non working/secure program is still a non working/secure program ^^

Comment: I did not actually expect such a good answer for that of a simple question! It is a great answer!

Comment: @M.K thank you. I edited again my answer to explain more that just `does not indicate if there is something wrong after the read number if you just use a simple "%d" for instance`

Comment: Thanks again bruno